# How to overwrite a BufferedImage drawn to JPanel outside PaintComponent() with getGraphics()

Tags: java, swing, graphics, alpha, java-2d

I am working on a simple 2D game.  Each tick, I want to check an effects queue that will start a thread for a certain effect(fading transitions, audio fade in and out, etc).  For example, pressing "Play" on the menu screen will add a "FadeOut" message to this queue, which will be processed and start a thread to draw a black rectangle with an increasing alpha value over my GamePanel.

I'm overriding paintComponent() and sending my Graphics object to my GameStateManager, which passes along the Graphics object to the current states' draw().  I currently don't have an effects state (which maybe I should) to route the paintComponent() graphics object to, but I do pass my gamepanel to my effects thread, where I can use getGraphics() to draw on it.  Drawing a rectangle to the GamePanel directly just causes flickering, as the gameloop is still rendering the game.

I found I can draw a black rectangle with increasing alpha to a BufferedImage, set the composite to AlphaComposite.Src (which causes the new draw to replace the old) then draw the BufferedImage over the game panel.  The problem is the BufferedImages drawn to the game panel don't get overridden each draw, so the fade out happens really quickly because these black BufferedImages of various alphas just stack on each other.

I wrote this short program to test composite settings and see what is getting overridden.  All drawing is done in the draw(), which would be my run() in the effects thread.

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ScratchPad extends JPanel implements Runnable
{
  private JFrame        oFrame         = null;
  private Thread        oGameThread    = null;
  private Graphics2D    oPanelGraphics = null;
  private Graphics2D    oImageGraphics = null;
  private BufferedImage oImage         = null;

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
  new ScratchPad();
}


public ScratchPad()
{
  createFrame();
  initPanel();
  addAndShowComponents();

  oGameThread = new Thread(this, "Game_Loop");
  oGameThread.start();
}


private void addAndShowComponents()
{
  oFrame.add(this);
  oFrame.setVisible(true);
}


private void initPanel()
{
  this.setOpaque(true);
  this.setBackground(Color.cyan);
}


private void createFrame()
{
  oFrame = new JFrame("Fade");
  oFrame.setSize(700, 300);
  oFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  oFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}


public void run()
{
  oImage = new BufferedImage(200, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

  while(true)
  {
    try
    {
      draw();
      Thread.sleep(100);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {

    }
  }
}


private void draw()
{
  oPanelGraphics = (Graphics2D)this.getGraphics();
  oImageGraphics = oImage.createGraphics();

  oImageGraphics.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);

  oImageGraphics.setColor(new Color(0,0,0,90));
  oImageGraphics.fillRect(0, 0, oImage.getWidth(), oImage.getHeight());
  oPanelGraphics.drawImage(oImage, 10, 10, null);

  oImageGraphics.setColor(new Color(0,0,0,60));
  oImageGraphics.fillRect(0, 0, oImage.getWidth(), oImage.getHeight());
  oPanelGraphics.drawImage(oImage, 220, 10, null);

  oImageGraphics.setColor(new Color(0,0,0,30));
  oImageGraphics.fillRect(0, 0, oImage.getWidth(), oImage.getHeight());
  oPanelGraphics.drawImage(oImage, 430, 10, null);

// Drawing this image over location of first image, should overwrite first 
// after setting composite to 'Src'

 oPanelGraphics.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
 oImageGraphics.setColor(new Color(0,0,0,10));
 oImageGraphics.fillRect(0, 0, oImage.getWidth(), oImage.getHeight());
 oPanelGraphics.drawImage(oImage, 10, 10, null);

 oImageGraphics.dispose();
 oPanelGraphics.dispose();
}
} // end class
```

What's interesting is setting the composite on 'oPanelGraphics' causes any alpha to the BufferedImage to go away, resulting in a fully opaque black image being drawn over the image that was previously there.  Even setting the color to something other than black doesn't have an effect.

What's also interesting is setting the composite for the BufferedImage to:

```
oImageGraphics.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcIn);
```

causes nothing to be shown.  The Oracle documentation on compositing graphics in Java2D states this for 'SrcIn':

"If pixels in the source and the destination overlap, only the source pixels in the overlapping area are rendered."

So, I would expect this to have the same behavior I get with AlphaComposite.Src.

Maybe someone out there can shed some light on whats going on with these composites, and how I could achieve my desired effect.

Comment: Cant you override the onDraw(Graphics g2d) in your panel instead of doing this draw() method?

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos Yes, that is what I'm doing currently.  However, my idea for handling effects in my game (transitions, screen and audio fade ins and fade outs) was to have actions (clicking "Play" on the menu, or character walks on certain tile) add messages to a queue that gets checked each game tick.  These effects will fire off a thread and be processed there, and the game loop can keep going.  I currently am not routing my paintComponent() provided Graphics object to my Effects class.  This is why I use getGraphics in the effects thread

Comment: Based on you code, you're not overriding `paintComponent` at all, but are using `getGraphics`, which is not recommended, as you're attempting to update the UI outside the context of the Swing defined paint cycle. You should also never dispose of a `Graphics` context you did not create. I also don't see the point of the `BufferedImage`. You also don't seem to have any concept over how animation is suppose to work in Swing

Comment: Based on what (little) I understand, what you actually need is one input (with no effects applied to it) and the output, with the effects applied. This means that on each paint cycle, you have the original, unaltered image, which the effects are then applied to, based on their properties and the duration they have been used

Answer (score 1):

There are a number issues with what you "seem" to be trying to do

- Don't call `getGraphics` on a component. This can return `null` and only returns a snapshot of what was last painted during a Swing paint cycle. Anything you paint to it will be erased on the next paint cycle
- You should also never dispose of `Graphics` context you did not create, doing so could effect other components that are painted by Swing
- Painting is compounding, this means that painting to the same `Graphics` context (or `BufferedImage`) over and over again, will continue to apply those changes over the top of what was previously painted
- You also don't seem to have a concept of how animation should work. Instead of trying to paint your fade effect in a single pass, where the results can't be applied to the screen, you need to apply a phase on each cycle and allow that to be updated to the screen before the next pass runs.

The following is a really basic example of what I'm talking about.  It takes a "base" image (this could be the "base" state of the game, but I've used a static image) and the paints effects over the top.

[image: Fade to black]

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Engine engine;
        private Image frame;

        public TestPane() {
            engine = new Engine();
            engine.setEngineListener(new EngineListener() {
                @Override
                public void updateDidOccur(Image img) {
                    frame = img;
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            engine.start();

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    engine.addEffect(new FadeOutEffect(Color.BLACK));
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return engine.getSize();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (frame != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                g2d.drawImage(frame, 0, 0, null);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

    }

    public interface EngineListener {

        public void updateDidOccur(Image img);
    }

    public class Engine {

        // This is the "base" image, without effects
        private BufferedImage base;
        private Timer timer;
        private EngineListener listener;

        private List<Effect> effects = new ArrayList<Effect>(25);

        public Engine() {
            try {
                base = ImageIO.read(new File("/Volumes/Big Fat Extension/Dropbox/MegaTokyo/megatokyo_omnibus_1_3_cover_by_fredrin-d4oupef 50%.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int width = base.getWidth();
                    int height = base.getHeight();
                    BufferedImage frame = new BufferedImage(width, height, base.getType());
                    Graphics2D g2d = frame.createGraphics();
                    g2d.drawImage(base, 0, 0, null);
                    Iterator<Effect> it = effects.iterator();
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        Effect effect = it.next();
                        if (!effect.applyEffect(g2d, width, height)) {
                            it.remove();
                        }
                    }
                    g2d.dispose();
                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.updateDidOccur(frame);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public void start() {
            timer.start();
        }

        public void stop() {
            timer.stop();
        }

        public void addEffect(Effect effect) {
            effects.add(effect);
        }

        public void setEngineListener(EngineListener listener) {
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        public Dimension getSize() {
            return base == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(base.getWidth(), base.getHeight());
        }

    }

    public interface Effect {
        public boolean applyEffect(Graphics2D context, int width, int height);
    }

    public class FadeOutEffect implements Effect {

        private int tick = 0;
        private Color fadeToColor;

        public FadeOutEffect(Color fadeToColor) {
            this.fadeToColor = fadeToColor;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean applyEffect(Graphics2D context, int width, int height) {
            tick++;
            float alpha = (float) tick / 100.0f;
            if (alpha > 1.0) {
                return false;
            }
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) context.create();
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, alpha));
            g2d.setColor(fadeToColor);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
            g2d.dispose();          
            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

Remember, every effect or change should be applied within the same "main loop", this means you shouldn't have multiple threads, in fact, since Swing is not thread safe, you should avoid having any additional threads if possible.  This example make use of a Swing `Timer` to act as the "main loop" because the `ActionLister`s `actionPerformed` method is called within the context of the EDT, making it safe to update the UI from. It also provides a simple synchronisation method, as the UI can't be painted while the `actionPerformed` method is been called

Comment: Thank you for the response.  So, you have a timer running all the time that checks the effects list?  And then you draw the current background onto a BufferedImage, then draw the effect on after, and pass back to the main panel which repaints to the screen?  Could I use a timer like this with the gameloop I already have in place?  It seems like either one or the other could be used.

Comment: Basically - the base image here could by dynamically create, but the idea is, each paint pass starts from scratch

Comment: So, I always have to start from paintComponent() and route that graphics object in an appropriate way.

Comment: If you want to use Swing, yes, you could use a BufferStrategy, which would give you complete access over the paint process

Comment: Why is use of getGraphics discouraged?  I thought there was only a chance it could return null if the panel was not visible yet.

Comment: @WhitJackman Calling getGraphics on a Component is discouraged because not only can it return null, it places you outside of the paint cycle, so anything you paint to it will be overridden the next time Swing performs a paint cycle, which can cause flickering. Swing has a week defined and documented paint process, which should be used if you want to perform custom painting with it